# Win API: How to catch every message from user input?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, windows-xp

I want to catch:

1. Window resize/move/minimize/maximize/close messages.
2. Mouseclicks and keyboard presses.
3. When any program was executed by the user either pressing enter or dblclick. (if possible?)

This should work the same way as the keylock programs works: if you do some event, i can decide via my program will i let Windows handle it, or do i handle it, or both.

How can i do this?

Comment: You'll have to pick another user name after you got SetWindowsHookEx() working.

Answer (score 1):

As Hans Passant pointed out, you need  the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
In the link all possible hooks are explained in detail and the hook functions you need to implement are as well. Here is a small example, how to install a global hook that will process messages, after they are processed by the window.

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

  HHOOK msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, msgHook, hInstance, 0);

  if(msgHook == NULL){
    //Error handling here
    cout << "Failed to set hook";
  }
  else{
    //Hook has been set and will automatically be removed, when your application exits.
  }

//A clean shutdown should always unhook everything it has installed
UnhookWindowsHookEx(msgHook);

return 0;
}
```

You can look up the hook functions definition in the MSDN, but it could look like this:

```
LRESULT CallWndRetProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

  CWPRETSTRUCT* theMessage = (CWPRETSTRUCT*)lParam;

  //now you can read all message parameters and the return value
  //...

  //Always return by calling the next hook in the chain
  return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The other hooks that you want to install follow the same principle.

See also

- [Hooks Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Using Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that there'll be some pain involved: Your hook procedure will have to be in a separate DLL (which will get injected into every process), and if you're on a 64-bit OS, you'll have to provide the DLL in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavors, to catch 'em all. Oh yes, and since you can only load a 64-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, your hooker-exe (the one which calls SetWindowHookEx) will also need to be in two flavors. Enjoy!